# Deleting corrupt data from elasticsearch after accidentally indexing multiple docs with wrong fields

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have written a python code that uses curl and gets time_download and some other info of specific websites and puts them into an index in Elasticsearch. The amount of data I am dealing with is huge. The application crashed and instead of time_download, it put the whole HTML of the website into my Elasticsearch. Now I have fields like "<html", ")}>", and many other junk fields. I also don't need the documents containing this kind of information in wrong fields. How can i delete the documents or fields?

The reason I want to delete them is I have added a new field but there's an error that says:
`{'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'failed to parse'}], 'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'failed to parse', 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded while adding new fields [1]'}}, 'status': 400}`

Also it has a very ugly view in my index management.

I was okay with these fields before because no one else could see them in Index Management but me and I was in a rush so ignored the problem. Now I have encountered this problem that I really need to delete them and only keep the fields that are important for me.

`GET _sql?format=txt { "query": "DESC [my_index_name]" }`

I have tried the above code and got lots of fields as some shown below:

[some of the field names in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqMcG.png)

Even the javascript code of one website is included as my FIELDS. Isn't that funny?

Comment: Kill the indices & start over with precautions Val suggested below. That's your only realistic option.

Answer (score 1):

You can run an `_update_by_query` on your index with an ingest pipeline using the `remove` ingest processor to remove all the fields that you want.

However, the mapping itself cannot be changed, fields that are there will stay there and will count to towards the 1000 field limit.

Your best option if you want to have a clean index going forward is to reindex it into another brand new index with the correct mapping, and eventually `dynamic: false` to prevent accidental field creation.